# Issues with 'PROPAGATE' and Collector node in IIB

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am trying to send multiple Collections to the same input terminal of a Collector node in my message flow as seen below:

[image: message flow]

The 'out1' terminal goes to an input terminal on Collector called 'in1' and 'out2' goes to an input terminal called 'env'. I only want one in1 and one env in a Collection together. There could be as many as 7 Collections overall.

In the ESQL there is a FOR loop iterating over a collection and based on some criteria either PROPAGATING a message to in1 and env or not. The propagate statements are inside this FOR loop.

This is the configuration on the Colelctor node. The number of messages is set to '1' for both input terminals as I only want one in1 and one env in a Collection.

[image: Collector node config]

The issue I am encountering is the following for a scenario with two Collections to be created:

1. Message1 is propagated to out1 / in1
2. Message1 is propagated to out2 / env
3. Message2 is propagated to out1 / in1
4. All processing stops. Flow sits idle for what is probably the expiry.
5. Message2 is propagated to out2 / env.

It appears the problem is in the Collector node, most likely the configuration settings and how I am sending messages to the input terminals. Does anyone who is familiar with using the Collector node see anything obvious that can be done to correct #4 above?

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you have your compute node working under transaction. The Collector node doesn't support receiving more than 1 message from the same transaction. Quote from the IIB knowledge center:

> If a transaction propagates more than one input message for the
>   Collector node, the Collector node does not behave as expected.

Check out the first Note:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac37820_.htm

The way you are trying to use the Collector node is quite strange. You seem to be generating the messages in the Compute node, so why not generate them grouped together in a single message tree there already?